Upgrade mysql version 5.7 to 8.0 in Docker. Error mysql auto restarting after upgrade
i have a docker-compose file like this
version: '3'

networks:
  my_network:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx_netnative_mi
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx/cms.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/cms.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/web.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/web.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - my_network
  mysql:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql_netnative_mi
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "33060:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./docker/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: tcss
      MYSQL_USER: net_native
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Concho!23456
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Concho!23456
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - my_network
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/.Dockerfile
    privileged: true
    hostname: php
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: php_netnative_mi
    volumes:
      - ./cms:/var/www/html/cms
      - ./web:/var/www/html/web
      - ./point.system:/var/www/html/point.system
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    ports:
      - "9090:9000"
    networks:
      - my_network
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis_netnative_mi
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./docker/redis:/data
    environment:
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
    ports:
      - "63790:6379"
    networks:
      - my_network
  redis_2:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis_netnative_mi_2
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./docker/redis:/data
    environment:
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
    ports:
      - "63799:6379"
    networks:
      - my_network

i upgrade mysql version 5.7 to 8.0 by change image in docker-compose file then compose down and compose run up -d --build to rebuild it and after upgrade mysql auto shutdow and restarting, when i check logs i got this logs.
2024-08-06 15:53:43 2024-08-06 08:53:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1.el9 started.
2024-08-06 15:53:44 2024-08-06 08:53:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-08-06 15:53:44 2024-08-06 08:53:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1.el9 started.
2024-08-06 15:53:45 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2024-08-06 15:53:45 2024-08-06T08:53:45.530028Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2024-08-06 15:53:45 2024-08-06T08:53:45.534107Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.39) starting as process 1
2024-08-06 15:53:45 2024-08-06T08:53:45.544571Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2024-08-06 15:53:45 2024-08-06T08:53:45.577703Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2024-08-06 15:53:45 2024-08-06T08:53:45.577909Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-08-06 15:53:45 2024-08-06T08:53:45.959946Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-08-06 15:53:46 2024-08-06T08:53:46.457281Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010520] [Server] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'mysql.sock'
2024-08-06 15:53:46 2024-08-06T08:53:46.461886Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010784] [Server] Failed to open dir /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
2024-08-06 15:53:46 2024-08-06T08:53:46.464861Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
2024-08-06 15:53:46 2024-08-06T08:53:46.464994Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-08-06 15:53:47 2024-08-06T08:53:47.796773Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.39)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-08-06 15:53:48 2024-08-06 08:53:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1.el9 started.
2024-08-06 15:53:49 2024-08-06 08:53:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-08-06 15:53:49 2024-08-06 08:53:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1.el9 started.
2024-08-06 15:53:50 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2024-08-06 15:53:50 2024-08-06T08:53:50.370565Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2024-08-06 15:53:50 2024-08-06T08:53:50.374388Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.39) starting as process 1
2024-08-06 15:53:50 2024-08-06T08:53:50.385070Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2024-08-06 15:53:50 2024-08-06T08:53:50.417655Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2024-08-06 15:53:50 2024-08-06T08:53:50.417846Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-08-06 15:53:50 2024-08-06T08:53:50.780713Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-08-06 15:53:51 2024-08-06T08:53:51.249180Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010520] [Server] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'mysql.sock'
2024-08-06 15:53:51 2024-08-06T08:53:51.253680Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010784] [Server] Failed to open dir /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
2024-08-06 15:53:51 2024-08-06T08:53:51.256715Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
2024-08-06 15:53:51 2024-08-06T08:53:51.256852Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-08-06 15:53:52 2024-08-06T08:53:52.600692Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.39)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-08-06 15:53:53 2024-08-06 08:53:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1.el9 started.
2024-08-06 15:53:53 2024-08-06 08:53:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-08-06 15:53:54 2024-08-06 08:53:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1.el9 started.
2024-08-06 15:53:55 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2024-08-06 15:53:55 2024-08-06T08:53:55.210088Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2024-08-06 15:53:55 2024-08-06T08:53:55.214068Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.39) starting as process 1
2024-08-06 15:53:55 2024-08-06T08:53:55.224619Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2024-08-06 15:53:55 2024-08-06T08:53:55.257097Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2024-08-06 15:53:55 2024-08-06T08:53:55.257290Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-08-06 15:53:55 2024-08-06T08:53:55.623085Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-08-06 15:53:56 2024-08-06T08:53:56.079094Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010520] [Server] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'mysql.sock'
2024-08-06 15:53:56 2024-08-06T08:53:56.083698Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010784] [Server] Failed to open dir /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
2024-08-06 15:53:56 2024-08-06T08:53:56.086924Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
2024-08-06 15:53:56 2024-08-06T08:53:56.087063Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-08-06 15:53:57 2024-08-06T08:53:57.429514Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.39)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-08-06 15:53:58 2024-08-06 08:53:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1.el9 started.
2024-08-06 15:53:59 2024-08-06 08:53:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-08-06 15:53:59 2024-08-06 08:53:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1.el9 started.
2024-08-06 15:54:00 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2024-08-06 15:54:00 2024-08-06T08:54:00.321010Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2024-08-06 15:54:00 2024-08-06T08:54:00.324905Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.39) starting as process 1
2024-08-06 15:54:00 2024-08-06T08:54:00.335363Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2024-08-06 15:54:00 2024-08-06T08:54:00.368169Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2024-08-06 15:54:00 2024-08-06T08:54:00.368362Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-08-06 15:54:00 2024-08-06T08:54:00.677913Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-08-06 15:54:01 2024-08-06T08:54:01.161680Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010520] [Server] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'mysql.sock'
2024-08-06 15:54:01 2024-08-06T08:54:01.166330Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010784] [Server] Failed to open dir /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
2024-08-06 15:54:01 2024-08-06T08:54:01.169499Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
2024-08-06 15:54:01 2024-08-06T08:54:01.169639Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-08-06 15:54:02 2024-08-06T08:54:02.494713Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.39)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.


i want mysql after upgrade version 5.7 to 8.0 can import the data i export from db mysql 5.7 and running well. If anyone know how to fix it please help me

Does ./docker/db contain old db files?  Delete them all if does. Or move to another directory for data backup.

thank you so much i backup my data then remove all file in ./docker/db and now everything working well
